# Fast graph viewer to view gnuplot generated graph in linux

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I generated a graph file using the following gnuplot command:

```
set term svg enhanced mouse size 1920, 1080
```

The data set I plotted contains 8*10^5 points. Each point is probably an int type (only value 1 and 0)

However, when I open the file using gnome-open in ubuntu. The graph takes time to load and it gets really slow when I tried to zoom in. In fact, I waited for 5mins, but I still did not see the zoom in graph. My machine is a decent one with i5 processor and 8GB RAM. So I doubt if the hardware has hard limitations to view the graph. How can I speed up the viewing process? (zoom in/out and view different part of the graph after zoom in)

Comment: What is the file size? And which application did you use in your attempt?

Comment: 59MB graph. Image viewer in ubuntu

Comment: And what if you try a few others? I mean image viewers are not _that_ hard to find...

Comment: Can you give some suggestions?

Comment: Try using one of gnuplot's interactive terminals (wxt, qt, x11, windows, aqua).